# Several issues with "adding custom behaviour to all repositories" in spring data jpa

Tags: java, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring data jpa and I am trying to add custom behaviour to all repositories as described here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

I encountered several issues:

-First, there is no such method as **getDomainClass** in the **RepositoryMetadata** class as described in the Spring documentation (see below):

```
protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      return new MyRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainClass(), entityManager);
}
```

I used the following method instead: **getDomainType()** Is this right?

-Second my application throws exceptions when tomcat starts. Here is the full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalRepositoryImpl' defined in file [E:\users\jumartin\dev_sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\
tmp0\wtpwebapps\SuiviTRC\WEB-INF\classes\trc\suivi\repository\GlobalRepositoryImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could
 not instantiate bean class [trc.suivi.repository.GlobalRepositoryImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: trc.suivi.repository.GlobalRepositoryImpl.<i
nit>()
```

Here is my custom global repository code:

```
public class GlobalRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GlobalRepository<T, ID> {

    private EntityManager em;

    public GlobalRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.em = em;
    }

    public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {

    }

}
```

Here is my xml config:

```
<repositories base-package="trc.suivi.repository" factory-class="trc.suivi.repository.GlobalRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <repository id="pliRepository" />
        <repository id="globalRepository" />
    </repositories>
```

I was not able to find any other sample on the web. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got some help and was able to get my repository to work by using the @NoRepositoryBean annotation on the intermediate interface.

Further info is available here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128536-Several-issues-with-quot-adding-custom-behaviour-to-all-repositories-quot-in-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 2):

I have made a full example of how to add custom behaviour to all repositories. 
http://borislam.blogspot.hk/2012/07/customizing-spring-data-jpa-repository.html

You could add features of different JPA implementation (e.g. hibernate, openJPA) to your base repository. I have made another tutorial on that.
http://borislam.blogspot.hk/2012/07/adding-hibernate-native-sql-features.html

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring Data JPA 1.9.M1 it's become easier to add custom methods to all repositories managed by Spring Data. [This](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/customall) example has all the details.

In your case the example would look like:

1) Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = GlobalRepositoryImpl.class)
class CustomRepositoryConfig {}
```

2) Custom base repository:

```
public class GlobalRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GlobalRepository<ID> {

    public GlobalRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {

    }
}
```

3) Some repository:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends GlobalRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Of course `GlobalRepository` still needs to be annotated with `@NoRepositoryBean`